# tcolorbox - Logo at the left of the title

Tags: formatting, tcolorbox

I would like to add a Font Awesome icon in the title of a `tcolorbox` but my MWE looks more like a makeshift job than a professional solution.

The problem I met is that the title is not centered horizontally and vertically.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
    title        = {\Large\faPython} \hfill Code Python \hfill\null,
    coltitle     = black,
    colbacktitle = black!10!white,
    colback      = white,
    center title
]

    Bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla,

\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
    title        = Code Python,
    coltitle     = black,
    colbacktitle = black!10!white,
    colback      = white,
    center title
]

    Bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla,

\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use an overlay.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,
    title        = Code Python,
    coltitle     = black,
    colbacktitle = black!10!white,
    colback      = white,
    center title,
    overlay={%
     \begin{tcbclipframe}
      \node[anchor=north west,inner ysep=1.5pt] at (frame.north west){\Large\faPython};
     \end{tcbclipframe}
     }
]

    Bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla,

\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you answer !